# How to set input of type date's value using JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is as follows:

```
var date1 = new Date($("#date1").val() + "T00:00");
date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 30);  // 30 days into the future

$date2 = $("#date2");  // input of type date
$date2.val(date1)
```

All work as expected, except the last line. The error says:

```
jquery-3.2.1.js:7990 The specified value "2021-07-02T03:00:00.000Z" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd
```

Comment: Whaddya mean 'sentences'?

Comment: I mean the first lines. The problem is in the last line.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work as expected? What error are you getting or how is it misbehaving?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has the same issue, this is how I solved it:

```
$date2.val(date1.toISOString().split("T")[0])
```

Comment: Nice! I did this the other day using regex. `new Date().toISOString().replace(/T.*/g, '')`